# Detecting change in size of getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, list, web, dom, mutation-observers

I am trying to develop a Chrome extension which replaces certain HTML in a list of elements that updates itself with time, but I can't find the right way to do it.

I have tried the following:

```
console.log("Getting nodes...")
var f = document.getElementsByClassName("myClassName")

function watch(data) {
    alert("Changed!!")
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(watch);
observer.observe(f.childList, {childList: true});
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Am I missing something? Perhaps there's a better way? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Comment: `console.log(f.childList);`

Comment: The `observe` method expects a single `Node` to be observed. `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is an array-like object with nodes. `HTMLCollection` does not have a `childList` property, so you're basically doing `observer.observe(undefined)`

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Then is it impossible to observe if one element on this list is added?

Comment: Surely not. Mind sharing your HTML to see what it is you're trying select and observe?

Comment: I don't have it here right now, but it's a list of elements of a social network posts which gets updated when the user scrolls down. The list adds elements correctly, but I can't find how to attach an observer to that list which reacts to changes in its size.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `forEach` on your list, and call `observe` for each node.

```
Array.from(elements).forEach(element => observer.observe(element, {childList: true}) )
```

The `childList` parameter is for children of each node, and not for a list of nodes.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work.

Comment: @xvlaze Is your selector returning elements?  Put a log statement in your loop to be sure. And put the child list param back in as well.

Comment: It's an HTMLCollection.

Comment: Yes, but does it contain any elements?

Comment: Yes! It is populated with the posts in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Select your elements with [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) if possible. Unlinke `getElementsByClassName`, `querySelectorAll` returns a snapshot of elements instead of *live list* which makes your result more predictable.

Either way, loop over the elements and call `observer.observe()` for each element in your list.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  alert('Changed!');
});

const options = {
  childList: true,
};

for (const element of elements) {
  observer.observe(element, options);
}
```

Comment: That's a nice approach, but how would the elements list change its size and launch the event? What I'm looking for is to react when that live list changes.

Comment: The thing is, you can't observe the `HTMLCollection` in that way. You have to observe the parent element where all child elements are added to.